# If elseif else in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a bat script for which I need to provide a parameter. If that parameter equals, "my-test1", it will execute a script. If that parameter equals "my-test2", it will execute another one. If the parameter does not exist in any of the if/elseif, return code 1.

How could I achieve this? Please find below what I've tried so far.

```
   if "%~1" == "my-test1" (
            python.exe mypath\my_test1.py
            )
    elseif "%~1" == "my-test2" (
            python.exe mypath\my_test2.py
            )
    else
        EXIT WITH AN EXECUTION CODE 1
```

Comment: `else` and `if` are separate keywords. Put a space between them.``EXIT WITH AN EXECUTION CODE 1` should be `exit /b 1` AND `else` must be on the same physical line as the `)` closing the true conditional processing AND `else must eitherbe followed by *some command(s)* or ` (` and commands on the next line(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`else` and `if` are separate keywords. Put a space between them.
`EXIT WITH AN EXECUTION CODE 1` should be `exit /b 1`

AND `else` must be on the same physical line as the `)` closing the true conditional processing

AND `else` must either be followed by *some command(s)* or `(` and commands on the next line(s)

ie.

```
 if "%~1" == "my-test1" (
            python.exe mypath\my_test1.py
            ) else if "%~1" == "my-test2" (
            python.exe mypath\my_test2.py
            ) else EXIT /b 1
```

Use `if /i`  to do a case-insensitive match

Answer (score 0):

If your scripts are genuinely numerically named, you can use `choice`:

```
@echo off
echo %1|choice /c 12 /m "my-test1 mytest-2"
python.exe "mypath\my_test%errorlevel%.py"
```

This will prompt the user if you run the file as is `filename.cmd` or it can be used with paramaters `filename.cmd 1`

if however you want to retain the current format to use specific input such as `filename.cmd my-test1` no need for `if` and `else`.

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "my-test1" python.exe "mypath\my_test1.py"
if "%~1" == "my-test2" python.exe "mypath\my_test2.py"
```